# How to execute long-running tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading

Executors are usually used when it comes to (short-running) tasks, but what is the best way to deal with tasks that are long-running, e.g. tasks that should run throughout the lifetime of an application?

Let's say I have an application in which a task that runs on a separate thread polls a directory for changes every X seconds. This task should never quit polling, unless the application quits. How do I start and manage this?

Would `new Thread(theLongRunningTask).start()` be such a bad option?

Answer (score 5):

This is also a use-case for the Executors framework, specifically [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). Just watch out for that thread hanging around when the app is done. You can use a custom `ThreadFactory` that makes daemon-threads. Or, if you want something simpler, use the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) API. You can construct a `Timer` with a boolean argument meaning "use daemon thread". You can also shut down the executor service explicitly when your application is ending.

Comment: Instead of threadfactory + daemon, you can shutdown the executor on exit (assuming the submitted tasks are interruption friendly and/or do not run all the time).

Comment: Yes, I agree - I'm not very fond of daemon threads as they can easily spin out of your control in terms of thread management.